I can't create a "Web User Control" and I don't have Visual C# in the add new file section
enter image description here
enter image description here
Currently, my visual studio does not have the "Web User Control" creation section and the Visual C# section that contains it
Am I missing something in my install modify?
I tried deleting and reinstalling visual studio 2022 but it still doesn't appear Visual C#

VS2022 does not install the legacy webforms workflows and tools by default.
So, you need to of course choose the asp.net workflows.
This one:

And then on the right side, expand the Installation details, and choose all of these I have selected:

So, in above, the must have are the 2 I highlighted with a blue mark, but in fact I suggest installing all of the selected items I have marked in above.
Quite sure vb.net and c# are selected, but I would check, and ensure this one:

With above, then say having created a asp.net c# .net framework webforms?
Then I am able to add or create a new user web control.
Hence this:

Of course, creating a user control applies to web forms, and thus I would assume that your project is an asp.net webforms project. Strange that your project only shows visual basic, and not c#? This suggests that you opened a vb.net project, and not a c# one.
Is your project a c# or vb.net project?
I would after installing the above workflows, try creating a new c# web forms project.
So, your project type for webforms should be one of these two types:
(vb.net, and c#)

Choosing either of the above two works fine, and if the project was vb.net, then the left site tree shows Visual Basic. If the project created was c#, then it shows c# as per above when I add a new user control to the project.
